# When does paho mqtt client drop buffered message?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am using Python based paho mqtt client to publish data to mosquitto mqtt broker.

Let's assume a scenario, when client wanted to publish message and broker got disconnected.

So python based client object buffers that message in _out_message (Ordered Dictionary), and keep retrying to send messages.

I wanted to know,

- For how long mqtt client will buffer such message?
- Is there any time limit or retry limit after which client will drop the message.

I wanted to dump/log such messages.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code?

Comment: I have done some level of code walk through, but didn't got any lead on deletion of buffered message? That's why I posted this question?

Comment: @barny, If you have any information on this, Please share your knowledge Or Please guide me to correct forum/place to visit

Comment: I have precisely the same level of knowledge as you. The source appears to show: a) the `out_messages` queue is only used for qos 1,2; and b) no obvious expiry on retries for unacknowledged messages. But feel free to check it yourself. Important for your use of the client to correctly handle `on_disconnect()` callback and returned values from publish call because the queue is by no means infinite.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Eclipse Paho Python documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/#client), you can set the maximum number of outgoing messages with Quality of Service greater than 0 (QoS > 0) that can be pending in the outgoing message queue with the method:

```
max_queued_messages_set(self, queue_size)
```

It seems that using the default value (0) all the messages are kept until the MQTT client is able to send them. So, in the end, I suppose that messages are kept until the Python process reach the memory limit imposed by the operating system.

[image: Screenshot taken from Eclipse Paho Python documentation]

You can force the MQTT client to discard messages using the method reinitialise.

```
reinitialise(client_id="", clean_session=True, userdata=None)
```