# Invalid Host after calling reinitialize() method - paho

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

So im trying to reset buffer by calling the reinitialize method, but after calling it i get ValueError: Invalid host.

The time.sleep(0.4) is simulating lag caused by postprocessing. The goal is to have less fps but live image.

This is my subscriber:

```
# set broker
MQTT_SERVER = "localhost"  #Write Server IP Address
MQTT_PATH = "test"

client = paho.Client()
client.connect(MQTT_SERVER, 1883, 60)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe(MQTT_PATH)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    imageStream = io.BytesIO(msg.payload)
    imageFile = Image.open(imageStream)
    cv2.imshow('Client',np.array(imageFile))
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    time.sleep(0.4)
    client.reinitialise()

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.loop_forever()
```

This is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-02d8506b1627> in <module>
     14 client.on_connect = on_connect
     15 client.on_message = on_message
---> 16 client.loop_forever()

c:\users\wikto\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py in loop_forever(self, timeout, max_packets, retry_first_connection)
   1777                 else:
   1778                     try:
-> 1779                         self.reconnect()
   1780                     except (OSError, WebsocketConnectionError):
   1781                         self._handle_on_connect_fail()

c:\users\wikto\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py in reconnect(self)
   1014         connect()/connect_async()."""
   1015         if len(self._host) == 0:
-> 1016             raise ValueError('Invalid host.')
   1017         if self._port <= 0:
   1018             raise ValueError('Invalid port number.')

ValueError: Invalid host.
```

Comment: Which buffer do you think you are resetting by calling `reinitialise()`? I don't think doing this will achieve what it appears you want as it's just going to add over head of rebuilding the connection. You would be better adding a mechanism to just ignore message in the `on_message` callback.

Comment: according to the comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60985568/when-does-paho-mqtt-client-drop-buffered-message - reinitialise should force client to discard messages